# Verb usage wth third peron

Tags: verbs

Why do we write. **He talks as if he were my master?** Shouldn't the verb be singular in this case? And if not then why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Were' in this case is not plural, it's the subjunctive form of the verb (which just happens to be the same word). It's used when you are referring to a situation that is not a real fact. "If I were Prime Minister, I would...".